# IE SCRIPT1028: Expected identifier, string or number

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internet-explorer, cross-browser

My Project is react typescript project and i am getting above error for the code below, it works properly for all browsers but fails in IE 11 and I feel it occurs for the ...prop, how can we simplify this code to work in IE 11. can anyone help me?

```
   const abc = function({prop}) => {
    const data = getData();
     return {
       ...prop,
       currentData : data,
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Arrow function expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), [rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) and [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) are all ES6 syntax, and they all don't support IE browser. please click previous links and check the Browser compatibility.

You could try to use [Babel.js](https://babeljs.io/repl) to translate the code to ES5 syntax.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Is there another solution which i can try??

Comment: You could try to install the [babel polyfill](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-polyfill) in the application, and here also have the [babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-arrow-functions) and [babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread) polyfills, please refer to them.